# Confusion in the output

Tags: c

I have just started my Data types revised chapter. I am currently studying the concept of signed and unsigned character. My doubt is that the signed char has a range from -128 to 127, then why the below code is still running ? Also, the below code is giving the infinite o/p which is not understandable to me.

```
main( )
{
char ch ;
for ( ch = 0 ; ch <= 255 ; ch++ )
printf ( "\n%d %c", ch, ch ) ; 
}
```

I am currently using GCC 32-bit compiler. Can anyone please help me in explaining the o/p of the above code ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Why shouldn't it run?

Comment: Also, the reason for the infinite loop is exactly that `127` is always less than `255`.

Comment: The code runs because the for loop always finds the condition to be true that is `ch<=255`

Comment: GCC will warn about this error if you have warnings turned on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ( ch = 0 ; ch <= 255 ; ch++ )
```

If `ch` is a signed character, it will start at 0 and increment to 127.  Then, at the next increment, it will "wrap around" and become -128.  Using an *unsigned* `char`:

```
127 = 0x7F
128 = 0x80
```

But, using a *signed* char, `0x80` becomes -128.

So now `ch` will run from -128 through 127.  And since all of those values are less than 255, this will repeat until you stop the program..

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. So according to you, the above code will run like this
ch=0 to ch=127
ch=-128 to ch=127
ch=-128 to ch=127
and so on until I will stop it. Correct ?

Comment: Yes.  That's exactly what happens when I compile and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Because signed character is from -128 to 127, its binary number are 10000000 and 01111111, When 'ch' run to 127, next increment 'ch' will become -128, always less than 255, so it will infinite o/p.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably confused with the output. I think in the o/p you are seeing something like this.

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3 ...
>
> 11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32...
>
> 33 ! 34 " ....
>   125 } 126 ~ 127
>
> 255 � 256  257
>
> ... 511 � 512  513  .. and so on

`0 to 32 are all flags(unprintable codes)`(hence you dont see the output , but only the numbers for the first 33), `followed by characters till 127`. As you can see it wraps around at every 255 characters to give you the same result `but it actually stops printing characters after multiples of 127`( this is the 127 char list - http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html) . It just resets after 127 to -128, so the program continues to print numbers to infinity even though it is resetting the char.
This is because when you do `printf("%d",ch) for -127 it prints 128`, and so on until ch = 255 and then it flips again and starts printing 256 onwards and so on but the **actual ch value never goes above 127 and hence it goes to infinity**

A `signed char c` should you be giving you the above output. A char is essentially an integer 8 bits wide, but by default probably signed on your compiler.

Comment: Using `unsigned char ch` would also loop endlessly as it`s `<=255` Mind the `=`.